# How to get sound card UMC204HD work properly under Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: drivers, sound, usb, soundcard, 23.10

Is there special configuration needed to get the external sound card UMC204HD running under Ubuntu 23.10?

I have it connected through USB and it worked perfectly fine under Ubuntu 22.04, but now under Ubuntu 23.10 it outputs the sound at about a volume of 50%. The only way to fix it I have found yet is to unplug the USB connection and then replug it. I have also checked for drivers, but only found some for Windows, but not for Linux.

[image]

Is there anything else that I should check? Anyone having the same experiences and a possible solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

I have UMC204HD and also have this exact issue. I'm not using Ubuntu either. I've found through searching that there's some fixes for various issues in the coming 6.8 version of the kernel. For example, https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/ae8b1631561a3634cc09d0c62bbdd938eade05ec

I've decided to just wait for that, and haven't looked into it more.